# Add / Replace operator to beginning of string with conditionals

Tags: javascript, string, lodash

Bit of a bloated question, so I'll lay it out in steps

I have three variables

```
let operators: = ['+', '−', '*', '/'];
```

The current user input (lets call it `currentUserInput`)

and the `newUserInput` (Whatever the user just typed)

I need to:

1. See if `newUserInput` contains any of the operators
2. If it does, add it to the beginning of `currentUserInput`, otherwise, add it to the end
3. If there is already an operator at the beginning of `currentUserInput`, replace it with the new one.

Example

If the `currentUserInput` is `+1234`
and the user types `/` anywhere in the input field, the new `currentUserInput` should be `/1234`

I have been using `if(operators.some(function(v) { return newUserInput.indexOf(v) >= 0; }))`

For step 1, which will give me a boolean response, but I need the operator being used as the response.

Comment: so, what did you tried so far?

Comment: when do you do this replacement, is it while the user is writing in an `input` ?

Comment: Yes, as soon as they type the operator

Comment: but, what if the user types as many operators as he wants: I.e `hdbd/jd+*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea is to append to the end of the string unless they have an operator as the new input? And if they have an operator already then replace the current operator otherwise prepend it. Assuming you want to do that try this code:

```
function processInput(currentInput, newUserInput) {
  let operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];

  if(operators.includes(newUserInput)) {
    var containsOperator = operators.some(operator => operator == currentInput[0]);
    return newUserInput + (containsOperator ? currentInput.substr(1) : currentInput);
  } else {
    return currentInput + newUserInput;
  }
}

console.log(processInput("-string", "+"));
console.log(processInput("-string", "s"));
console.log(processInput("string", "+"));
console.log(processInput("string", "s"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses RegExp to replace the operator at the start of the string, or the start of the string, if no operator is found.

```js
const operators = ['+', '\\-', '*', '/'].join('');
const searchPattern = new RegExp(`[${operators}]`);
const replacePattern = new RegExp(`(^[${operators}]|^)`);

const replaceOperator = (currentUserInput, newUserInput) => {
  const operator = newUserInput.match(searchPattern);
  
  if(!operator) return currentUserInput;
  
  return currentUserInput.replace(replacePattern, operator[0]);
}

console.log(replaceOperator("-string", "+"));
console.log(replaceOperator("-string", "s"));
console.log(replaceOperator("string", "+"));
console.log(replaceOperator("string", "s"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach utilizing only `includes` and ES6 basic string manipulation:

```js
let ops = ['-', '+', '*', '/']
 
const fn = (c, n) => ops.includes(n) ? ops.includes(c[0]) ? `${n}${c.substr(1)}` : `${n}${c}` : `${c}${n}`

console.log(fn("-string", "+"));
console.log(fn("-string", " and stuff"));
console.log(fn("string", "-"));
console.log(fn("string", " baby"));
```